# Error starting raspberry pi

Tags: pi-3, wifi

I am a complete newbie to raspberry pi. I am running my pi on my windows laptop using WinSCP. My pi was working all fine and then there was some connection error so I tried to reconnect it. I am getting a network timed out error. I thought that there might be an error with the host name of my pi and I tried checking its IP address from the list of devices connected to my router, but my router shows that raspberry pi is not connected to it. I have created an empty ssh file in my SD card and the following is my wpa_supplicant.conf file:

```
country=IN 
update_config=1 
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
network={ 
  scan_ssid=1 
  ssid="JioFi2_C7B2B0" 
  psk="***********" 
  }
```

I was actually trying to use my pi to start a hotspot and had used the following command when the error occurred:

sudo service dhcpcd restart

Is the error happening because of this command?

Where am I going wrong and what should I do to make it work?

Comment: You did not read the responses at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=219200 carefully enough. There are still at least 2 issues that you did not address...

Comment: What does "I am running my pi on my windows laptop" mean?

Answer (score 1):

There are several problem with your .conf file.
Try

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=IN

network={
    ssid="network-name"
    psk="network-password"
}
```

Comment: 1: no. 2: no. But 'ctrl_interface' line is wrong. And I'm fairly sure that wpa does not like the spaces in front of the '}'. Not 100% sure about that one though.

Comment: oh damn - I didn't see the difference in the ctrl_interface line ... sorry :p will remove my comment

Comment: I applied your changes, yet my pi is not being shown in the list of devices being connected to my router.